# Python: Is there a way to use a set amount of inputs?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this simple python webhook sender for Discord with 3 inputs for the URLs.
I want to figure out how to make on option to use 1, 2 or all 3 of the inputs. Is that possible?
I'm not the most experienced person so please answer in some detail.

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook

print('paste webhook 1')
url1 = input()

print('paste webhook 2')
url2 = input()

print('paste webhook 3')
url3 = input()

print('what do you want them to say?')
content = input()
print('sending...')

while True:
    webhook_urls = [url1, url2, url3]
    webhook = DiscordWebhook(url=webhook_urls, content=content)
    response = webhook.execute()
```

Comment: Hi! We can answer in more detail if you explain the situation in more detail. What determines how many inputs to use? Is this something you ask the user for beforehand, or do you just want them to leave it blank if it should be skipped?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I would like to ask the user beforehand

Comment: Great! So try adding that question to your example. (I’m a big proponent of teaching to fish.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you would initially ask them how many webhooks they want to input

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook


def ask_for_count():
    webhooks_num = input('How many webhooks would you like to use? (1, 2 or 3) \n')
    # Firstly, you don't need a seperate print statement to ask for input
    # it can be in the input function and if you need the answer in a new line,
    # use the escape character /n which creates a new line after execution.
    return webhooks_num


def get_webhooks():
    if count == '1':
        url1 = input('paste webhook 1 \n')
        webhook_urls.append(url1)
        return # The return ends function as soon as the urls are added to the list.

    elif count == '2':
        url1 = input('paste webhook 1 \n')
        url2 = input('paste webhook 2 \n')
        webhook_urls.append(url1)
        webhook_urls.append(url2)
        return

    elif count == '3':
        url1 = input('paste webhook 1 \n')
        url2 = input('paste webhook 2 \n')
        url3 = input('paste webhook 3 \n')
        webhook_urls.append(url1)
        webhook_urls.append(url2)
        webhook_urls.append(url3)
        return

    else:
        print('Please enter a valid choice.')


def get_content():
    answer = input('what do you want them to say? \n')
    print('sending...')
    return answer


webhook_urls = []
# List is intentionally outside of the function,
# so that you don't create an empty list everytime the function is called.

# Now you call the functions defined above to execute in order.
count = ask_for_count()
get_webhooks()
content = get_content()


while True:
    webhook = DiscordWebhook(url=webhook_urls, content=content)
    response = webhook.execute()
```

So, basically, as soon as the program runs, the user is asked for the number of webhooks needed and then based on the input (out of 3), they get asked for the webhooks which are then added to the webhook_urls list initiated earlier.

After that, the user is asked for the content and the while loop initiates, executing the code normally, using the function outputs and the list initiated earlier; webhook_urls.

Hope I helped.